# How to detect directional signal in three dimensions?

Tags: filters, 3d

I have three orthogonal accelerometers that give accelerations in x,y and z dimensions. I'm trying to detect directional vibrations between certain frequencies.

In other words, my input is 3d vector and I would like detect signal coming from unknown direction, filter out noise from other directions and turn the signal into normal scalar for further processing.

Comment: What kind of signal are you trying to detect?  Is this on Earth with a constant gravitational acceleration that can vary with orientation?